# Ember.js and CKEDITOR conflict: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ckeditor, wysiwyg

There is a conflict between Ember.JS and CKEDITOR. The toolbar (modal windows) doesn't work if I am using Ember.js. If I try to push e.g. the paste button then I get the following error message and the window is whited out with no modal window.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

[image: ckeditor toolbar not working]

If I remove Ember.Js then CKeditor works fine.

See a live demo of the problem on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/HEhMq/13/

This is how I'm embedding the CKEDITOR to my ember templates:

```
App.HTMLTextArea = Ember.TextArea.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this._super();
        var self = this;
        var elementId = self.get('elementId');

        var edit = CKEDITOR.replace( elementId, {
            extraPlugins : 'autogrow',
            autoGrow_maxHeight : 800,
            // Remove the Resize plugin as it does not make sense to use it in conjunction with the AutoGrow plugin.
            removePlugins : 'resize'
        });

        edit.on('blur', function(e) {
                if (e.editor.checkDirty()) {
                        self.set('value', edit.getData() );
                }
        });
    }
});
```

With this code the editor loads up fine and the Ember values are updated. It's just the toolbar buttons that are not working.

Anybody had the same problem?

Comment: The jsfiddle you attached shows normal editor - there's no error and no Ember code. Could you check it?

Comment: The error is when you try to push a button on the toolbar that opens a modal window. The ember.js is included, there is no need for actual ember code. The point is that because of Ember there is a conflict and those toolbar buttons don't work. If you remove ember from the resources, then the buttons work fine

Comment: Would you be able to put up an ember example of using ckeditor? I can't seem to get it workign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luckily, it turns out that we've already fixed this issue: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10265 We did that just few days ago and new version (4.1.1) which is planned for next week will contain this patch. In fact, master on CKEditor repo is already frozen for the release, so you can use it because it's very unlikely that something is going to change.

Comment: Thanks for the info Reinmar! It's working now with CKEditor version 4.1.1 :)